# Appium test returns exit code 2 error in app center

Tags: java, android, appium

My appium android test compiles successfully on local. I prepared and uploaded the same test on app center's test cloud following the prep guidelines: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/preparing-for-upload/appium.

I Packed the test class and all dependencies into the `target/upload` folder and performed the upload. The project was scanned and the runner class was correctly identified. Console says `Build Success` but the test did not run. The output says `Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0`

A final error was displayed: `Cannot run tests. Returning exit code 2`

[image]

[image]

From the logs, what could I have done wrong? I did a google research and found that exit code 2 means `Invalid Options` but what on earth does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

This most likely is a naming issue.

According to the Maven Surefire conventions for inclusion of tests you must name the tests:

"**/Test*.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that start with "Test".
"**/*Test.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Test".
"**/*Tests.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Tests".
"**/*TestCase.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "TestCase".